# Show input value in the closest div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return the value of each input its closest div. Each div has the different name but same div class next to it. The problem is I cannot find the closest div class with jquery. But the value from typing `keyup` sent succesfully.

```js
        $('.bk_name').on('keyup', function() {
          var q = $(this).val();
          $(this).parent().closest('div.resp').html(q);
      console.log(q);
        }); //keyup
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name1</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[1]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>


<br />
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name2</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[2]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>
```

For the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/s85n42eo/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(this).next('div.resp').html(q)` or `$(this).parent().find('div.resp').html(q)`

The problem is that you are using `.closest()` it will search for parents, not look for children.

**Demo**

```js
$('.bk_name').on('keyup', function() {
  var q = $(this).val();
  console.log($(this).parent().find('')
  $(this).next('div.resp').html(q);
  console.log(q);
}); //keyup
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name1</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[1]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>


<br />
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name2</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[2]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is working. But why I use the same code with ajax. It's not working???

Comment: @Wilf I can't tell you why it's not working in your ajax without seeing the code.

Comment: But a wild guess about why it's not working in ajax, could be the use of `$(this)` depending on your code

Comment: Sorry, this is the code https://jsfiddle.net/2jrm06hv/

Comment: @Wilf As i thought, $(this) is the problem, do it like https://jsfiddle.net/d48xao5y/

Comment: It's working! Your code works like god! Can I ask, what's the different between `$this` and `$(this)`? I tried change it back and it stuck!

Comment: @Wilf there is no difference, problem is that $(this) inside your success is no longer the related to `$('.bk_name')` but your ajax

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
 .find()
```

when yo want to search for a nested element.

since you bubble up 1 element using `.parent()`  you get to the `<div class="col-sm-5">` element. from there you are trying to reach a child element `<div class="resp">` - you can do that with `.find`

[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree while
[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) does the opposite

```js
$('.bk_name').on('keyup', function() {
          var q = $(this).val();
          $(this).parent().find('div.resp').html(q);
      console.log(q);
        }); //keyup
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name1</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[1]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>


<br />
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>Name2</label>
  <input type="text" class="bk_name" name="bk_name[2]" />
  <div class="resp"></div>
</div>
```